# PHP convert XML to JSON group when there is one child

Tags: php, xml, json, simplexml, converters

I use this PHP class to convert XML to JSON:http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xml2jsonphp/

For example for this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<searchResult>
    <status>OK</status>
    <users>
        <user>
            <userName>johndoe</userName>
        </user>
        <user>
            <userName>johndoe1</userName>
            <fullName>John Doe</fullName>
        </user>
        <user>
            <userName>johndoe2</userName>
        </user>
        <user>
            <userName>johndoe3</userName>
            <fullName>John Doe Mother</fullName>
        </user>
        <user>
            <userName>johndoe4</userName>
        </user>
    </users>
</searchResult>
```

The result is:

```
{
  "searchResult": {
    "status": "OK",
    "users": {
      "user": [
        { "userName": "johndoe" },
        {
          "userName": "johndoe1",
          "fullName": "John Doe"
        },
        { "userName": "johndoe2" },
        {
          "userName": "johndoe3",
          "fullName": "John Doe Mother"
        },
        { "userName": "johndoe4" }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But i would like:

```
{
  "searchResult": {
    "status": "OK",
    "users": [
      { "userName": "johndoe" },
      {
        "userName": "johndoe1",
        "fullName": "John Doe"
      },
      { "userName": "johndoe2" },
      {
        "userName": "johndoe3",
        "fullName": "John Doe Mother"
      },
      { "userName": "johndoe4" }
    ]
  }
}
```

Grouping "user" in "users", because this is an array with just one child.

I've search another class to convert XML to JSON to have this result but i've not find any ressources.

Can you please help me to solve my problem.

Thanks in advance, best regards Fabrice

Answer (score 0):

The article you've linked is pretty outdated. For example [`Services_JSON`](http://pear.php.net/package/Services_JSON/) is *normally* not needed any longer.

The stable PHP 5.4 version right now has [`json_encode()` function](http://php.net/json_encode) and the [`JsonSerializable` interface](http://php.net/class.jsonserializable) as well as [`iterator_to_array`](http://php.net/iterator_to_array). Even if you're using the older PHP 5.3 version, the following example is pretty easy to adopt.

So what you actually need is your own JSON encoding of a `SimpleXMLElement`.

So first of all, let's just create "our own" Json encoder:

```
class XML2Json extends SimpleXMLElement
{
}
```

Wow. That was dead simple. Let's check that it works:

```
$converter = new XML2Json($bufferXml);

echo json_encode($converter, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT), "\n";
```

And the result is already similiar to the result with `Services_JSON`:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "users": {
        "user": [
            {
                "userName": "johndoe"
            },
            {
                "userName": "johndoe1",
                "fullName": "John Doe"
            },
            {
                "userName": "johndoe2"
            },
            {
                "userName": "johndoe3",
                "fullName": "John Doe Mother"
            },
            {
                "userName": "johndoe4"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But this is not fitting. As the output shows, the *searchResult* property is missing and also the users are not in a single array like you want them.

So the `json_encode` needs to be user-defined. To do this in PHP, PHP has the `JsonSerializable` interface. It consists of a single method named `jsonSerialize()` and we will make it return a different value now if the name is *searchResult* to offer both it's name as property and the users as a flat array. Let's extend and implement the interface:

```
class XML2JsonSearchResult extends XML2Json implements JsonSerializable
{

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        $name = $this->getName();

        if ($name !== 'searchResult') {
            return $this;
        }

        $value          = (array)$this;
        $value['users'] = iterator_to_array($value['users']->user, FALSE);

        return [$name => $value];
    }
}
```

All elements that don't have the name *searchResult* will get their default JSON encoding by returning `$this`.

The *searchResult* will be named and it's users are flattened by the `iterator_to_array()` function.

And that is all you need to do. Again the usage-example, it works exactly the same, only this time the class-name differs:

```
$converter = new XML2JsonSearchResult($bufferXml);

echo json_encode($converter, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

And the output now is like you want it:

```
{
    "searchResult": {
        "status": "OK",
        "users": [
            {
                "userName": "johndoe"
            },
            {
                "userName": "johndoe1",
                "fullName": "John Doe"
            },
            {
                "userName": "johndoe2"
            },
            {
                "userName": "johndoe3",
                "fullName": "John Doe Mother"
            },
            {
                "userName": "johndoe4"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Hope this gives you a good example how to do it nowadays.

The whole code-example at a glance ([Online Demo](http://eval.in/32839)):

```
class XML2JsonSearchResult extends SimpleXMLElement implements JsonSerializable
{

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        $name = $this->getName();

        if ($name !== 'searchResult') {
            return $this;
        }

        $value          = (array)$this;
        $value['users'] = iterator_to_array($value['users']->user, FALSE);

        return [$name => $value];
    }
}

$converter = new XML2JsonSearchResult($bufferXml);

echo json_encode($converter, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I don't know that's possible to "format" the json_encode function.
So I try to edit the jsonSerialize method to can be compatible with all of my json data.
I post them when it's ok.
Thanks again, Fabrice

Comment: Just reviewing this because of some different question. What you might also need is to collapse all elements that have a single child element which again is an array of children. This could be tested as well and those (like users->user) could be automatically collapsed (like users here).