# Pluralize array names in XML objects using simplexml

Tags: php, xml

I am using `simplexml` to load an XML file and encode the content in JSON format so that it can be consumed by another part of my application. Everything works fine but I noticed that `simplexml` generates singular names for "arrays", for instance, this piece of XML:

```
<employees>
    <employee>
        <name>John M.</name>
        <age>34</age>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Sarah J.</name>
        <age>31</age>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

Once that I load the XML code in a PHP object using:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("employees.xml");
```

I have to use the singular form for access the arrays of employees, for instance:

```
$xml->employee[1];
```

But I want to pluralize names of arrays. The major reason for doing this is because I want to generate JSON from that XML object directly using `json_encode`, rather than generating a new array/object with the respective name pluralized.

It is possible to change this behavior? If this cannot be accomplished within `simplexml` how would be the best approach to resolve this?

Comment: Some example code can be found in an [answer to a related question (PHP convert XML to JSON group when there is one child)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16938322/367456), coming from a different problem, there is also [Part III in a series of posts regarding SimpleXML and JSON](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2013/07/10/simplexml-and-json-encode-in-php-part-iii-and-end/) that shows a solution decorating SimpleXMLElement that is superior over extending it that is commented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is possible to change this behavior?

Short answer: no.

---

You're going to want to "*generate [something] with the respective name pluralized*".  In any case, I would advise against simply [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode)-ing [`SimpleXMLElement`](http://php.net/simplexmlelement) objects anyway.

In the long run (and in your case, it seems, the short run) you'd be better off:

- changing the XML document to have pluralised element names
- or, doing some work yourself as an intermediate step between SimpleXML and `json_encode()`

---

As for "*the best approach*" (for serializing anything as JSON), I would advise going for your own class (perhaps extending [`SimpleXMLElement`](http://php.net/simplexmlelement)) that implements the [`JsonSerializable`](http://php.net/jsonserializable) interface. Other options include changing the XML as mentioned above, or building your own array/object structure to JSON encode, to name a few.

Answer (score 0):

When you say:

> But I want to pluralize names of arrays.

It makes little sense.  The XML parser in [`simplexml`](http://php.net/simplexml) is just regurgitating what it sees.  And in your XML structure:

```
<employees>
    <employee>
        <name>John M.</name>
        <age>34</age>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>Sarah J.</name>
        <age>31</age>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

There is indeed an overarching `<employees>` hierarchy. But each employee record, the employee is stored as the singular `<employee>`. Which is returned in an array appropriately named `$employee`.

If it’s confusing to you, just ad a few more steps to the XML to JSON conversion to achieve your goal:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("employees.xml");
$xml2json = (array) $xml;
$json_employees = json_encode(array('employees' => $xml2json['employee']));

echo '<pre>';
print_r($json_employees);
echo '</pre>';
```

The JSON output would be:

```
{
    "employees": [
        {
            "name": "John M.",
            "age": "34"
        },
        {
            "name": "Sarah J.",
            "age": "31"
        }
    ]
}
```